# randomly assign a string to all rows in a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df['type']`where I want to randomly assign one of the two string values: hello, bye to all rows in this column. How can I do so?

Comment: `np.random.choice`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) with length of `DataFrame`:

```
df['type'] = np.random.choice(['hello','bye'], size=len(df))
```

For boolean:

```
df['type'] = np.random.choice([True, False], size=len(df))
```

Or:

```
df['type'] = np.random.choice([1, 0], size=len(df), dtype=bool)
```

Comment: can this be modified to assign boolean values (0/1) as well?

Comment: @x89 - Sure, change `['hello','bye']` to `[0,1]`, for boolean `np.random.choice([0,1], size=len(df), dtype=bool)`

Comment: `random.choice()` is in the standard library. There is no need to use numpy.

Comment: @Bachsau For performance is used np.random.choice

Answer (score 1):

use the module random

```
random.choice(["hello","bye"])
```